# Remover sublinhados no VScode (image 1 = problema, image 2 = solution)

Tags: visual-studio-code

Como remover esses sublinhados que dificultam leitura do código no meu VScode.

[image: clique aqui para ver o problema]

[image: clique aqui para ver a solução]

Comment: Solution ver resposta no link abaixo: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60012502/how-to-disable-peek-problem-in-vs-code-resolvido

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Esse tipo de "warning" existem para várias linguagens e para situações diferentes, pode ser um erro, ou um alerta ou apenas um atributo experimental não reconhecido.

Vc pode tentar colocar no `JSON` dos seus  `setting` assim, já que o problema é no JS.

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "experimentalDecorators": true,
        "allowJs": true
    }
}
```

Caso não funcione, uma "gambiarra" seria colocar todos os `decorations` de alerta com a cor transparente, assim eles ficam invisíveis na tela...

```
{
    "workbench.colorCustomizations": {
        "editorError.foreground":   "#00000000",
        "editorWarning.foreground": "#00000000",
        "editorInfo.foreground":    "#00000000"
    }
}
```

Comment: Obaaa, vou usar sua gambiarra pois tenho mesmo problema em todos arquivos, não somente js.

Comment: @ViviSantana se vc considerar que resolveu o problema depois lembresse de marcar a resposta como aceita nesse ícone ✔️ abaixo das setinhas ao lado da resposta. []´s